# use XML loaded number as a function variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use a variable from the code below in a link ID to load an overlay iframe. I'm loading numbers from an XML file that I'm using for each generated link parameter, I could use them as an ID too. Below is the javascript:

```
$(function(){
$('#b1').frameWarp();
});
```

Instead of using ID="b1", am I able to create variables based on the loaded XML numbers?
I cannot use class instead of ID.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use:

```
$('#' + varName).frameWarp();
```

Apologies if this isn't what you're looking for.  I'm having trouble understanding your question.

Comment: I'm using an XML file that has a number for each section. The page loads a link for each section of the XML and puts the article number in the URL parameter (page.html?aid=###) and when the link is clicked an overlay iframe pops up the  with more information about that article. The link ID is calling the overlay iframe popup but I can't use more than one of the same ID for a page. With the code above, how could I get varName to recognize many different numbers?